# Custom C++ string class

Tags: c++

I am creating a class that works similar to the string class. I am in a starting stage doing some experiments.

Assume all header files are added

```
class String
{
      public: 
          int len; 
          char *str = NULL;                                                                       

      // Default constructor 
      String()
      {                                             
           len = 0;
           str = new char[1];             
           str[0] = '\0';
           printf("New memory: %p\n", str);
      }

    // Copy constructor
    String(const char *ch)
    {
        len = strlen(ch);  

        if (str != NULL)
        {
            printf("Old memory: %p\n", str);
            delete str; 
            printf("Deleted...\n");               
        }

        str = new char[len + 1];
        printf("New memory: %p\n", str);

        for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
            str[i] = ch[i];
    }
};


int main()
{
    String msg;

    std::cout << msg.len << std::endl;
    std::cout << msg.str << std::endl;

    msg = "Hello";
    std::cout << msg.len << std::endl;
    std::cout << msg.str << std::endl;
}
```

When I create a String object 1 byte of memory is allocated to store string and initialises with `\0` on line `String msg;`

When copy constructor is called on line `msg = "Hello";` it first checks for any previous allocation of memory and to avoid memory wastage it will `delete` that and recreates a new memory block.

The issue is when `copy constructor` is called line `if (str != NULL)` is not getting executed. It should execute because `str` is allocated a byte of memory earlier in `default constructor` and it is not NULL.

What may be the thing that I missed out?

Comment: That's not a copy constructor. That's a constructor that takes a `const char*`. A copy constructor would have the signature `String(const String& other)`

Comment: Doesn't C++ (including its various libraries) have more than enough string classes already? Why create yet another one?

Comment: When you call a non-default constructor for a class, the default constructor is not called beforehand. When you enter `String(const char*)` your `String` is in the same state as if you just entered `String()`. That means `str == NULL`. Also use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: @JohnFilleau We have an answer section for answers. Thanks.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Learning? Practice? It's a pretty common exercise, is it not?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings but your answers are much better than mine and I haven't had my second cup of  coffee yet. (you're right though I'm bad about that)

Comment: *What may be the thing that I missed out?* -- The [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  Especially read the **Managing Resources** section of that link.

Comment: @JohnFilleau ok sorry my mistake I miss understood it as copy constructor. Then what would be the better name for that? A conversion constructor as mentioned by Asteroids With Wings

Comment: @Jesper Juhl. Yes we have. It is purely to understand the things and how it works by some simple experiments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does this:

- Default-construct a `String` "A"
- Convert-construct a temporary `String` "B" from the expression `"Hello"`
- Copy-assign "B" to "A"

The assignment does *not* invoke the constructor on "A". You only get one construction per object.

Unless you specify otherwise (with delegating constructors), your default constructor is *not* invoked before the "copy constructor" (or a conversion constructor like yours) is run.

So this:

> It should execute because str is allocated a byte of memory earlier in default constructor and it is not NULL.

is wrong.

`String(const char *ch)` needs to allocate.

Also, because you're performing assignment, you're going to need to implement a copy assignment operator to make that safe.

Comment: Ah, now I see where your misconception lies.